# How can get a position in a List in Haskell using Maybe

Tags: haskell

I have to write a function in Haskell for:

```
safeIndex :: [b] -> Integer -> Maybe b
```

so when it get an Element from a List it will give us a `Just` when it does not it gives us `Nothing`

```
ghci> [1..10] 'safeIndex' 3

Just 4

ghci> [1..10] 'safeIndex' 10

Nothing
```

and I really not succeeding in that

Comment: kind of homework.. it's training for the lecture

Comment: Nope.. not this one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a small change from the unsafe version.

```
(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
[]     !! n = error "What"
(a:as) !! 0 = a
(a:as) !! n = as !! (n-1)
```

Instead of failing with `error` we should fail with `Nothing`. This will cause the rest of the function to fail to typecheck as our return type has changed

```
(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> Just a
```

To fix this, we must tag successes with `Just` as well. Finally, the recursive call should be thought carefully about. Does it require a tag of any kind? It depends on whether or not it fails, but we can't know that until we actually step into the recursive call...

Answer (score 1):

I will give you hints on how to achieve that:

- Think of the case on what to do when the input list is empty.
- Think of the alternative case on what to do when the input list is non-empty.

You have to solve it using recursion. When you have an empty list, you have to return `Nothing`. In case you find an element for a particular index you can wrap the result in `Just` and return it. I think it should be now straight forward enough to translate this into Haskell code.

Comment: safeIndex :: [b] -> Integer -> Maybe b

safeIndex  [] = Nothing

tell here I have the half of it.. I got the problem with the other Part, How  wrap the result in Just and return it

Comment: @user3604901 See @bheklilr's function definition and try to fill the `???` in it. His definition also shows you how to wrap the result in `Just`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), it doesn't look like one exists in the base libraries, but you could write one pretty easily, although I would name it `!?`:

```
(!?) :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
[]     !? _ = Nothing
(x:xs) !? 0 = Just x
(x:xs) !? i = ???
```

I'll leave you to fill in the `???` case, you can get some hints from @Sibi's answer to do so.  Keep in mind that this doesn't handle negative indices, if you want that as well then I'd suggest using guards instead:

```
[] !? _ = Nothing
(x:xs) !? i
    | i < 0  = ???
    | i == 0 = Just x
    | otherwise = ???
```

Comment: I think ^^ 2 weeks programmer, it still hard for me :D

Comment: or it will be **safeIndex  (x:xs)  i =  xs safeIndex (i-1)**

Comment: @user3604901 That last one is what you're after